# CloudFront is using SSL?

Tags: cdn, amazon-cloudfront

I have a less-compiled file on my server, lets say `domain.com/style.css`, inside it there are `http://` calls and it works just fine.

When I try to serve this file via `CloudFront`, such as `http://cdn.domain.com/style.css` the http calls inside the CSS file turn into `https://` which breaks the calls. any idea why?

Comment: How did you configure the Origin Server's "Origin Protocol" on CloudFront?  You can set CloudFront to use HTTP, HTTPS, or "Match Viewer," which is probably the correct choice.  CloudFront never rewrites content.

Comment: HTTP...thats the first thing I checked